# Inboxes: Why aren't pings ponging?

Tags: bug, comment-replies

I asked this question on EL&U meta and was advised to ask over here.

People seem to be not getting pung by other peoples messages recently. I've seen several comments about it, and people I've pinged ain't been getting punged either. Also messages aren't getting into my inbox.

This isn't happening with all messages just some. I know of at least three other users who have experienced this over the last few days.

Specifically, so far, F.E., StoneyB (members on that site) and I have all had problems with a) not getting messages left under our posts (either pinging or inbox), b) not getting messages which have been addressed to us either by being pinged, or in our inboxes. They just aren't appearing in inboxes at all sometimes.

Are the powers that be aware of the pinging crisis?

**An example**

- [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254271/relative-adverbs/254275?noredirect=1#comment556064_254275) [User not getting messages left under own post]

Comments to me were subsequently deleted so, I now can't find them, but will add more examples as they occur. If anyone else has any, perhaps you could add them here too.

Comment: pung? Not pinged?

Comment: @Oded just to lighten the tone. Has more comic irony on the English Language & Usage site! :)

Comment: "pong" would be better, taking the game "ping pong" as source. You ping, the target is ponged.

Comment: Anyway, you really must bring some examples. We can't possibly guess..

Comment: Well, further debugging is due then e.g. can he see notifications for those comments in his full inbox now? (available in his network profile, or link in the bottom of the top bar inbox, labelled "see all inbox items")

Comment: @ShadowWizard I shall have to check with him. However, I know for a fact that messages that I'd left for F.E. weren't pinging him *or* appearing in his inbox *and* aren't there now.

Comment: Well, there's always the chance of temporary down time of some server/service responsible for those notifications... @Oded might be able to dig into the logs and see.

Comment: The title triggers "flag as spam" reaction. Suggest revising.

Comment: May I humbly suggest "Why aren't pings ponging?" Maybe prepended with "Inbox messages:".